# Remove Kernel Array method

Tags: ruby

I would like to know how to remove the method `Kernel.Array.rand`. When the user tries to call it, it should give an error; any kind of error would do.

I tried as below. I tried `Kernel.Array` and `Kernel::Array` instead of `Random`, but they did not work too.

```
class << Random; self; end.send :remove_method, :rand
```

Using my IRB I saw that:

```
2.0.0-p195 :028 > Kernel.Array.rand
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
from (irb):28:in `Array'
from (irb):28
```

And was even available in the autocomplete with tab.

Tried the rand because was necessary to avoid any use of random method. So I need to remove also sample and shuffle from the Array.

But look what I get:

```
class << Array; self; end.send :remove_method, :sample
NameError: method `sample' not defined in Class
from (irb):31:in `remove_method'
from (irb):31
```

So, I would still know how to remove a method from the Array, in that case should be related to the Kernel.Array.

Comment: What is `Kernel.Array.rand`?

Comment: There's no `rand` method on array

Comment: I explained better my case. I thought that didn't exist also, but look my edited post please.

Comment: @CassioS.Cabral: "wrong number of arguments" error is about `Kernel.Array` expression. `rand` was not called on that (due to the error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `undef_method` (the difference with `remove_method` is that `undef_method` will walk up the inheritance chain)

```
rand # => 0.3417719504956065

Kernel.send :undef_method, :rand # private method, have to use `send`

rand # ~> -:5:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `rand' for main:Object (NameError)
```

### Update

Ah, you are confused. There is a `Kernel::Array` **method**, which is completely different from `Array` the **class**. Also, there's no need to obfuscate your code with those eigenclass constructs. You can do simply this:

```
module Kernel
  undef_method :rand
end

class Array
  undef_method :sample
end

rand # ~> -:9:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `rand' for main:Object (NameError)
[1, 2].sample # ~> -:10:in `<main>': undefined method `sample' for [1, 2]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Removed the rand just fine, thanks. My problem is with the Array class. I edited my question so can reflect that. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @CassioS.Cabral: Just to be clear, the problem was that you were trying to remove the `sample`
 method from Array's eigenclass rather than from Array itself.